# Export HTML Table to Excel including Textarea and Dropdown Selected Values

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to save an HTML table to excel that contains dropdown lists and comment fields.

I am able to save the static information just fine, but the comment (textarea) and dropdown (selected value) does not come across.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>

<script>

function fnExcelReport(){
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>"; // bgcolor will give color to your first row
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('tblData'); // id of table

    var table = document.getElementById("tblData");

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    { 
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    //alert(tab_text);
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Submit.xlsx");
    }  
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

    return (sa);
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Pass or Fail</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="15" title="Enter comments if necessary" name="comment" placeholder="Comments" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
        <td>
        <select name="cars" autocomplete="off" class="passFail")">                  
                    <option name="default" value="default" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Pass or Fail</option>
<option value="pass">Pass</option>
<option value="fail">Fail</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="15" title="Enter comments if necessary" name="comment" placeholder="Comments" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
        <td>
        <select name="cars" autocomplete="off" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">                    
                    <option name="default" value="default" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Pass or Fail</option>
<option value="pass">Pass</option>
<option value="fail">Fail</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 3</td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="15" title="Enter comments if necessary" name="comment" placeholder="Comments" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
        <td>
            <select name="cars" autocomplete="off" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">                    
                <option name="default" value="default" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Pass or Fail</option>
                <option value="pass">Pass</option>
                <option value="fail">Fail</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport('headerTable', 'test results');"> EXPORT </button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the header rows and Test 1, Test2, and Test3, but where the comments and dropdown is, I actually get the comment field and dropdown list in Excel and not the values that have been entered in HTML.

Would it be better to go through the table cell by cell and write that to Excel, or go column by column and treat cols 2 and 3 different because I will not use .innerHTML?

Answer (score 3):

The code can be used in a simple way by just calling the function and passing the table DOM element as a parameter on click of a button or else on some events. In some cases, we don't have to export certain column or certain fields, so we use a set of custom defined class names that recognizes certain columns and input tags respectively. Below is the code for the same.

```js
$("#btnExport").click(function(){
      var $table = $("#tblExportGrid");
      ExportHTMLTableToExcel($table);
   });
 function ExportHTMLTableToExcel($table) {
        var tab_text = ""
        var final_text = "";
        var filename = $table.attr('export-excel-filename'); // attribute to be 
        // applied on Table tag
        filename = isNullOrUndefinedWithEmpty(filename) ? "Excel Document" : filename;
        var index = $table.find("tbody tr").length;
        if (Number(index) > 0) {
            $.each($table, function (index, item) {
                var element = $(item);
                var headertext = $("#" + element[0].id).closest
                    (":has(label.HeaderLabel)").find('label').text().trim();
                if (headertext == "") {
                    tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr>";
                }
                else {
                    tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr> " + headertext + "</tr><tr>";
                }

                // Create column header
                element.find("thead tr th").each(function () {
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("NoExport"))
                        tab_text = tab_text + "<td bgcolor='#87AFC6'>" +
                            $(this)[0].innerHTML + "</td>";
                });

                //Close column header
                tab_text = tab_text + "</tr>";

                // Create body column
                element.find(" tbody tr").each(function () {
                    tab_text = tab_text + "<tr>";
                    $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).hasClass("ExportLabelTD")) {
                            var value = $(this).html();
                            tab_text = tab_text + "<th>" + value + "</th>";
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).find("input,select").each(function () {
                                var value = "";

                                if ($(this).prop("type") == 'select-one') {
                                    value = $('option:selected', this).text();
                                } else {
                                    value = $(this).val();
                                }

                                if (!$(this).closest("td").hasClass("NoExport") &&
                                    !$(this).hasClass("NoExport")) { // NoExport is used for TD 
                                    // or tan input tag that not needs to be exported
                                    tab_text = tab_text + "<th>" + value + "</th>";
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    tab_text = tab_text + "</tr>";
                });

                // Create colum footer
                element.find("tfoot tr td").each(function () {
                    var colspan = $(this).attr("colspan");
                    var rowspan = $(this).attr("rowspan");

                    colspan = colspan == undefined ? 1 : colspan;
                    rowspan = rowspan == undefined ? 1 : rowspan;

                    if ($(this).hasClass("NoExport")) {
                        tab_text = tab_text + "";
                    }
                    else if ($(this).hasClass("ExportValueTD")) // Footer class that needs 
                    // to be no td that have input tags
                    {
                        $(this).find("input,select").each(function () {
                            var value = "";

                            if ($(this).prop("type") == 'select-one') {
                                value = $('option:selected', this).text();
                            } else {
                                value = $(this).val();
                            }

                            if (!$(this).closest("td").hasClass("NoExport") &&
                                !$(this).hasClass("NoExport")) {
                                tab_text = tab_text + "<td colspan=" + colspan + "";
                                rowspan = "" + rowspan + " > " + value + "</th>";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        tab_text = tab_text + "<td colspan=" + colspan + ""; 
                    rowspan = "" + rowspan + " > " + $(this).html() + "</td> ";
                });

                tab_text = tab_text + "<tr></tr></table>";

                if (index == 0) {
                    final_text = tab_text;
                }
                else {
                    final_text = final_text + tab_text;
                }
            });

            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match
                (/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                txtArea1 = window.open();
                txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                txtArea1.document.write(final_text);
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus();
                sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, filename + ".xls");
                return (sa);
            }
            else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
            {
                //sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + 
                //         encodeURIComponent(final_text));
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +
                    encodeURIComponent(final_text));
                anchor.setAttribute('download', filename);
                anchor.style.display = 'none';
                document.body.appendChild(anchor);
                anchor.click();
                document.body.removeChild(anchor);
            }
        }
    }

    function isNullOrUndefinedWithEmpty(text) {
        if (text == undefined)
            return true;
        else if (text == null)
            return true;
        else if (text == null)
            return true;
        else
            false;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" />
<table id="tblExportGrid" export-excel-filename="New Document">
   <thead>
      <th> First Column </th>
      <th> Second Column </th>
      <th class="NoExport"> Third Column </th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" value="First 1" /></td>
         <td class="ExportLabelTD"> Second 1 </td>
         <td class="NoExport"> Thrid 1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" value="First 2" /></td>
         <td class="ExportLabelTD"> Second 2 </td>
         <td class="NoExport"> Thrid 2 </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <td class="ExportValueTD"><input type="text" value="Foot First 1" /></td>
         <td> Foot Second 1 </td>
         <td class="NoExport"> Foot Thrid 1 </td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went cell by cell and where I had the dropdown list, I just asked for the text.

```
for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
        if (c == 2 && r > 0) {
        passFail_row = ("passFail" + r);
        var sel = document.getElementById(passFail_row);
        var text= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    }
    else 
        alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerText);
    }
}
```